# Designer not working for Android Xamarin app

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I am 100% new to Xamarin seem to have done something wrong in Visual Studio 2015.  I am just trying to view my Main.axml file however the designer is giving me the following error:
A valid Android SDK could not be found. An existing SDK with platform tool and at least one platform needs to be registered with the IDE.

[image]
Do I need to do soemthing specific to fix this?
[image]

As you can see I am targeting Android 4.1 API 16.

Another weird issue is that the Android SDK Manager is disabled is this normal?

visual studio -> tools ->options:
[image]

To launch Android SDK Manager I have to launch Android studio and click on Android SDK Manager :
[image]

Comment: One of the solution could be to move android sdk to path without spaces

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue with my sdk on visual studio. I could not open sdk manager from visual studio and xamarin designer could not open even though i pointed to an sdk location. however, other things worked correctly. Updating sdk from android studio and upgrading jdk to 1.8.0_102.   solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

While the Xamarin is updating, that error can see.

Solved is found the tools zip file:

C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\temp\tools_r25.2.4-windows (or your active last tools, doesnt matter. for ex. tools_r23.0.1)

-> Open that zip and unzip in "tools" folder.

-> Cut that folder and, paste parent folder (C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk)

Answer (score -1):

Delete files from this path:

```
C:\Users\ ++ Your Windows Account Here ++ \AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache\
```

Comment: Delete Files From This Path

Comment: Consider adding an explanation to your answer.